# Can a default function return auto?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider the following class:

```
class example
{
public:
    auto & operator =(const example &) = default;
    auto & operator =(example &&) = default;
};
```

Are those declarations considered legal?

Comment: I'm no language lawyer, but I imagine the answer is "no" since there is no `return` statement present for `auto` to deduce a type from. What is wrong with simply writing out `example&` instead of `auto&`? You are already writing out `example` in the input parameters anyway.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Nothing wrong with it. Class names can get long and I figured it couldn't hurt to ask.

Comment: `auto` is not a return type, it is a keyword used in a shorthand way to declare a return type.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> ```
> auto & operator =(const example &) = default;
> auto & operator =(example &&) = default;
> ```
>
> Are those declarations considered legal?

No.

> [dcl.spec.auto] ... If the declared return type of the function contains a placeholder type, the return type of the function is deduced from non-discarded return statements, if any, in the body of the function ([stmt.if]).

A defaulted function definition does not have a body, which conflicts the quoted rule. There is nothing that the return type could be deduced from and there is no rule that states what that type would be in this case.

`operator<=>` has an exceptional rule specifying what the return type will be when `auto` is used as shown in [Caleth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62565551/2079303), but `operator=` does not have such rule. I see no reason such rule couldn't be introduced to allow auto in defaulted assignment operators.

Comment: I *think* `= default;` counts as the body of the function, but that doesn't change your argument, as it has no `return`

Comment: @Caleth That appears to be the case grammatically. Technically, a function body without return statement is not a problem with auto because in that case it is deduced as void. That seems a bit dubious in case where the "body" cannot have any statements. In case this is reasonable interpretation, the problem becomes that void doesn't match the type that the implicitly declared operator would have which is required by another rule.

Answer (score 13):

### In C++20, Yes<sup>1</sup>

> Let `R` be the declared return type of a defaulted three-way
> comparison operator function, and let `xi` be the elements of the
> expanded list of subobjects for an object `x` of type C`.
>
> - If `R` is `auto`, then let `cvi Ri` be the type of the expression `xi <=> xi`. The operator function is defined as deleted if that
>   expression is not usable or if `Ri` is not a comparison category type
>   ([cmp.categories.pre]) for any `i`. The return type is deduced as the
>   common comparison type (see below) of `R0, R1, …, Rn−1`.

[`[class.spaceship/2]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/class.compare#class.spaceship-2)

### Before C++20, No

> A function definition of the form: *attribute-specifier-seq opt
> decl-specifier-seq opt declarator virt-specifier-seq opt* `= default ;` is called an explicitly-defaulted definition. A function that is
> explicitly defaulted shall
>
> - be a special member function,
> - **have the same declared function type** (except for possibly differing ref-qualifiers and except that in the case of a copy
>   constructor or copy assignment operator, the parameter type may be
>   “reference to non-const `T`”, where `T` is the name of the member
>   function's class) as if it had been implicitly declared, and

[`[dcl.fct.def.default]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct.def.default) (emphasis added)

1. But only `<=>`. A defaulted `==` must return `bool`, and assignment has similar restrictions as previous standards.

> if `F` is an assignment operator, and the return type of `T1` differs
> from the return type of `T2` or `T1`'s parameter type is not a
> reference, the program is ill-formed;

[`[dcl.fct.def.default]`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.fct.def.default#2)

Comment: You should say whether the assignment operator case has changed as well. That is, you should say if the *only* defaulted function that can use `auto` is `<=>`

Comment: This is more accurate answer!

Answer (score 8):

*not a language lawyer answer*

From my experience compilers don't accept `auto` return type for defaulted special member functions, so I assume they are indeed not allowed by the standard.

The only exception I know of is the C++20 default three-way comparison operator:

```
#include <compare>

struct X
{
    auto operator<=>(const X&) const = default;
};
```